# How to code if else based on decision tree

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement, decision-tree

I have a decision tree with Yes/No questions that includes the output. How can i implement such code using if else statement with yes/no button in Android Studio? Please help me with some code.

Here is my decision tree:

[my decision tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezKEI.png)

Comment: Your question is too broad in its current format.  I have worked with decision trees and with Java/Android, and what you are asking for would take a ton of code and logic.  If you can narrow your question down to a specific programming problem, then please do so.

Comment: I'm sorry if you think the question is too broad, Have you checked on the picture of my decision tree? That's all I have for now.